# Reading Json without a property name

Tags: c#, json, json.net

we have the following invalid Json being returned from a customer of ours, is there any way we can convert this to a valid json object using newtonsoft library ?

Tried to load this invalid json using JToken in JsonConverter but its throwing an exception

> *Invalid character after parsing property name. Expected ':' but got: }. Path 'description[0]'*

```
//Invalid Json
{ "description": [{"Apple"}]}


//Valid Json
{ "description": [{"type": "Apple"}]}
```

Thanks in advance
-Nen

Comment: An invalid `Json` is invalid for `Json.Net` operations.Let your customer know that it's wrong in the beginning.

Comment: Your customer is creating the problem. Better to get them to fix it at their end rather than trying to patch dodgy data..

Comment: If you have specified JSON as the encoding then they are breaking your specification.  Better to have them fix their broken code than try to fix it for them, both because it's more compliant and because they need to learn the lesson.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, it's better to fix the source of the invalid JSON response than patch your code, however here's a suggestion:

```
string invalidResponse = @"{ ""description"": [{""Apple""}]}";
string validRespone = invalidResponse.Replace(@"""description"": [{", @"""description"": [{""type"":");
```